# Why is my WCF callback timing out?

Tags: .net, wpf, wcf, events, wcf-callbacks

I have the following service and callback contracts (abridged):

**Service Contract:**

```
[ServiceContract(CallbackContract = typeof(ISchedulerServiceCallback))]
public interface ISchedulerService
{
    [OperationContract]
    void Stop();

    [OperationContract]
    void SubscribeStatusUpdate();
}
```

**Callback Contract:**

```
public interface ISchedulerServiceCallback
{
    [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)] 
    void StatusUpdate(SchedulerStatus status);
}
```

**Service Implementation:**

```
[CallbackBehavior(UseSynchronizationContext = false, ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Multiple)] // Tried Reentrant as well.
[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single)] // Single due to a timer in the service that must keep time across calls.
public class SchedulerService : ISchedulerService
{
    private static Action<SchedulerStatus> statusUpdate = delegate { };

    public void Stop()
    {
        Status = SchedulerStatus.Stopped;
        statusUpdate(Status);
    }

    private SchedulerStatus Status { get; set; }

    public void SubscribeStatusUpdate()
    {
        ISchedulerServiceCallback sub = OperationContext.Current.GetCallbackChannel<ISchedulerServiceCallback>();
        statusUpdate += sub.StatusUpdate;
    }
}
```

**Service Consumer:**

```
public class SchedulerViewModel : ViewModelBase,  ISchedulerServiceCallback
{
    private SchedulerServiceClient proxy;

    public SchedulerViewModel()
    {
        StopScheduler = new DelegateCommand(ExecuteStopSchedulerCommand, CanExecuteStopSchedulerCommand);
    }

    public void SubScribeStatusCallback()
    {
        ISchedulerServiceCallback call = this;
        InstanceContext ctx = new InstanceContext(call);
        proxy = new SchedulerServiceClient(ctx);
        proxy.SubscribeStatusUpdate();
    }

    private SchedulerStatus _status;
    private SchedulerStatus Status
    {
        get
        {
            return _status;
        }
        set
        {
            _status = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public void StatusUpdate(SchedulerStatus newStatus)
    {
        Status = newStatus;
        Console.WriteLine("Status: " + newStatus);
    }

    public DelegateCommand StopScheduler { get; private set; }

    bool CanExecuteStopSchedulerCommand()
    {
        return true;
    }

    public void ExecuteStopSchedulerCommand()
    {
        proxy.Stop();
    }
}
```

The `SchedulerViewModel` is bound to a simple window with a textbox and a button, through its `Status` and `StopScheduler` properties. The WCF is hosted by a simple Console app for debugging: the solution is set to start the service host (console app) first, and then the WCF app.

When I click the button on the main app window, I expect the command to be invoked, i.e. calling `proxy.Stop();`. This should change the status of the service's status and invoke the callback. I think it does, but the callback times out. The debugger hangs on the line `proxy.Stop();`, and eventually I get the error message:

> This request operation sent to
>   http://localhost:8089/TestService/SchedulerService/ did not receive a
>   reply within the configured timeout (00:00:59.9990000).  The time
>   allotted to this operation may have been a portion of a longer
>   timeout.  This may be because the service is still processing the
>   operation or because the service was unable to send a reply message. 
>   Please consider increasing the operation timeout (by casting the
>   channel/proxy to IContextChannel and setting the OperationTimeout
>   property) and ensure that the service is able to connect to the
>   client.

When I use the `SchedulerViewModel` in a Console app, the callback works fine, and the viewmodel prints `Status: Stopped` in the console window. As soon as I involve other threads, the callback no longer works.
Other threads being the viewmodel raising `OnPropertyChanged` to updated the bound textbox, and I don't know if any more threads are involved in enabling/disabling the command.

Nothing in the service method invoked should take more than milliseconds at most, and I believe I am heading in the right direction believing this is a threading and/or UI hangup issue, as I have seen similar problems while doing research. Most were quite different scenarios and deeply technical solutions.

Why is this happening, and is there nothing I can do, using fairly standard WPF and WCF infrastructure and functions, to enable this callback? My sad alternative is for the service to write the status to a file, and the view model to watch the file. How is that for a dirty workaround?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, you are creating a deadlock in WPF.

1. You block your UI thread when you call `Stop` synchronously.
2. Server processes `Stop` request and before returning back to the client processes all callbacks.
3. Callback from server is processed synchronously so it blocks returning from `Stop` until your callback handler in WPF handles `StatusUpdate` callback. But the `StatusUpdate` handler cannot start as it needs UI thread - and the UI thread is still waiting for the original request to `Stop` to finish.

If you are using NET 4.5, the solution is easy. You "click" handler will be marked as `async` and you call `await client.StopAsync()` in your client.

```
var ssc = new SchedulerServiceClient(new InstanceContext(callback));
try
{
    ssc.SubscribeStatusUpdate();
    await ssc.StopAsync();
}
finally
{
    ssc.Close();
}
```

If you are using NET 4.0, you will need to invoke `Stop` asynchronously in some other way. Most likely through TPL.

You don't have this problem in your console client because it just fires callback on different thread.

I've created very simple solution showing the difference between WPF & Console App on [GitHub](https://github.com/milanio/SO-28837505). In the WPF client you will find 3 buttons - showing 2 ways how to fire `Stop` asynchronously and 1 sync call which will cause the deadlock.

In addition, it seems to me that you don't handle **unsubscribe** at all - so once your client disconnects the server will try to invoke dead callback - which can and most likely will also cause calls to `Stop` from other client(s) to timeout. Therefore in your service class implement something like:

```
public void SubscribeStatusUpdate()
{
    var sub = OperationContext.Current.GetCallbackChannel<ISchedulerServiceCallback>();

    EventHandler channelClosed =null;
    channelClosed=new EventHandler(delegate
    {
        statusUpdate -= sub.StatusUpdate;
    });
    OperationContext.Current.Channel.Closed += channelClosed;
    OperationContext.Current.Channel.Faulted += channelClosed;
    statusUpdate += sub.StatusUpdate;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for such a comprehensive answer.  I can't test it right away, but I think it's worth accepting anyway. I have just removed all 'outgoing messages' from the WCF, and only raising events to its host to signal exceptions. 

Status updates are handled are handled by a timer only model that calls the WCF, and updates the viewmodel.. Only one 'long running' WCF method is called from the UI, and that is called using `await`. I want to revisit callbacks using `async`, but I can't go making more changes until I deliver at least an alpha version.

Comment: No worries, good luck with alpha! Once you are able to test it just use the example project which is attached to the answer - it shows the different approaches to the callback handling.

Comment: I have made several tactical changes since asking this question, and am only now trying your answer on a pretty different angle, but you have helped me get the callback working, albeit different. However, I still have some issues, maybe for another question, but, in your example off GitHub, I see you instantiate and subscribe a proxy in each handler. Is there reason for this, vs. doing this in my viewmodel ctor?

Comment: Hi @ProfK, no there is no reason why you have to subscribe every time - the GitHub example was just to demonstrate how the deadlock occurs and how to avoid it. You can subscribe your VM when you initialize it and then disconnect only when you are disposing the VM. The client should keep the channel open or it can miss some events fired on the server.

Comment: Ya, thanks, @milanio. I wasn't sure cos I finally got the callback working,  but was having a few issues. One being I can't subscribe in my VM until the WCF is hosted; fixed by re-instantiating and subscribing the VM when its polling tells it the host is running.